# Request is not available in this context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net application. I have created a BasePage class inherited from the Page class. That BasePage is being inherited by all the aspx pages. There is a function to set the session in the BasePage. Below is the code

```
public class BasePage : Page
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }


        public BasePage()
        {
            if (!SetSession())
            {
                Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
            }

        }

        private bool SetSession()
        {
            if (Request!=null && Request.QueryString["myvalue"] != null)
            {

                    this.UserName = ....
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
         }
```

There is a default.aspx page which is being inherited by the BasePage. As soon as I fetch the default.aspx page it shows the error "Request is not available in this context". I am using Windows Server 2003. Can anyone help me out to resolve this issue.

Comment: what is Request and where have you defined/declared it ??

Comment: Request is the HttpRequest property of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try using request like below

```
HttpContext.Current.Request
```

Instead of refering it from `Page` class

**Update copy of working code (Tested)**

```
public partial class _Default : BasePage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    public class BasePage : Page
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }


        public BasePage()
        {
            if (!SetSession())
            {

            }

        }

        private bool SetSession()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["myvalue"] != null)
            {


            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @user1053922 Its working with me. There might be some other issue. Can you specify which line throws this error? Remember to update both Request reference in the if condition.